# Performance hit of "Automatically detect settings" for the first request

Tags: .net, proxy, httpwebrequest

I have the following piece of C# code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/");

    var response = request.GetResponse();

    response.Close();

    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

If I check the **Automatically detect settings** check box on IE (system) proxy settings, I am getting this output:

```
12164,0891
265,8832
248,4743
235,4291
239,6717
234,2011
236,3179
287,2781
239,5829
248,0245
```

If I uncheck it, I am getting these results

```
991,2215
269,6613
241,1335
241,2875
234,1904
227,1039
226,7818
224,4154
227,6287
224,3641
```

As you can see, there is a huge impact on first request when I enable auto proxy detection. I've tried to implement the workaround explained in the following article but to no avail:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielvl/archive/2009/03/23/faster-proxy-detection-for-httpwebrequest.aspx

Is there any way to minimize (or better get rid of) this impact on first request? Disabling the **Automatically detect settings** is not an option because we should respect the user's proxy settings.